# How to call cmd to execute a command using wix?

Tags: wix, windows-installer

Note the cmd.exe must be called only after the installation has taken place. I tried reading the WIX document and have implemented the same code but it still fails. Could some one tell me what the problem is?

[image: Custom action error]

```
<CustomAction Id="MyAction"
              Property="INSTALLDIR"
              Execute="commit"
              ExeCommand='[SystemFolder]cmd.exe "c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\regasm" /codebase /tlb "[installdir]\[lib]\x64\xDotnet.dll"'
              Return="check"
              Impersonate ="yes" />

<InstallExecuteSequence>
    <Custom Action="MyAction" Before="InstallFinalize" />
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

Comment: [Please have a look here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51092664/129130) (use of heat.exe to extract COM registration data). It has been quite a while since I looked at this though. Add the full path to heat.exe if need be and try to run the command and see what you get out. Run on your main development computer.

Comment: No problem. I recommend you use the heat.exe approach if you can. The use of RegAsm.exe on target boxes adds a lot of clunk. As I said I have not used this a lot as of late. Please test on clean virtuals as well as real boxes.