# Run external batch script inside of SourceDir from msi with SourceDir as Working Directory

Tags: windows-installer, custom-action, orca

I need to run an executable inside of SourceDir while installing an application. The msi database already exists. I try to alter it using Orca.

The executable itself is located inside of SourceDir. I further need to set the working directory to the executable location befor running it.

I know I can create CustomActions of type 50 or 34. I was able to run the executable with a CustomAction of type 34 with the predefined SystemDir as working directory. But how can I set SourceDir or a subdirectory as working directory?

Comment: Batch files should not be used with MSI installations. [However you can have a look here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51092664/129130).

Comment: For CA Type 34, the "Source" column is the Working Directory and the "Target" column is for the filename and commandline

Comment: You also can start your batch by this: `cd "%~dp0"` to work in the batch directory